# VHDL Testbench over simulate

Tags: vhdl, testbed

Why should I create a testbench/testbed in VHDL? Isn't it just as good to sit and manipulate the signals in the simulator to ensure that the VHDL code behaves correctly?

Comment: [You want the ability to automate your testing.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_automation)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a testbench.

1. You can re-run it any time and extend it as the design grows.
2. You can make it self-checking - compare outputs with expected values, assert when anything's wrong, and report a summary of any errors.
3. You can use the full programming language to generate comprehensive tests, or random tests if the design is too large to test every input value
4. You can read files generated by Matlab or whatever, and write files of results to process and display in Matlab to prove its accuracy
5. You never need to pore through waveforms unless the self-checking reports an error, then display all the signals for further debugging.
6. You can make your testing semi- or even fully automatic.
7. Even if you do none of these, a minimal testbench that just drives the inputs and you have to examine the waveforms serves as the basis for something better later on.
8. (thanks to Morten) You can quickly modify an existing test case to recreate a reported bug in simulation, which gives you full visibility into signals and enables fixing much faster.
9. A VHDL testbench is usually portable, (reading/writing binary files is the one exception I know about, but text files are OK) so you aren't stuck using one specific toolchain.

Comment: X. You can quickly modify an existing test case to recreate a reported bug in simulation, which gives you full visibility into signals and enables fixing much faster.

Comment: Y: You can automatically run multiple testcases in parallell on a cluster to speed things up when your design gets bigger.
Z: You can get nice statistics such as code coverage reports, giving you a decent idea about which parts of the design you have not tested fully.

Answer (score 1):

I’m totally with you man. I definitely just force signals when I test my designs. Test-benches are only really good for two things.

1. Communication
2. Large tests

Explanation:

1. How do you plan to show others that your hardware works? Do you plan to sit there and manipulate each input and then run? It’s much more efficient and less time consuming (on the viewer end) to write an automated test-bench or forces file.
2. What if you want to test a hundred different random inputs? Or read inputs from a file? Testbench testbench testbench.